# Do we need [stylesheet]?

Tags: discussion, burninate-request

I just stumbled upon [stylesheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stylesheet). The current tag wiki is a bit ambiguous.

> A style sheet is made up of style rules that tell a browser how to present a document. It uses style sheet languages like CSS or XSLT. Questions related to design will come under this tag.

What does it mean that "questions related to design will come under this tag"?

Since we have [css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css) and [xslt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xslt), I see [stylesheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stylesheet) as redundant.

Comment: I just rediscovered [tag:styles], which is slightly worse (but someone caught it at least).

Comment: In my opinion it should be made a synonym of [tag:css].

Comment: @ʎǝʞuoɯɹǝqʎɔ that is Kevin's proposed solution below

Comment: @ʎǝʞuoɯɹǝqʎɔ: Merging tags is not the same as making them synonyms. In particular, as mentioned, "stylesheet" can refer to a number of things and does not always pertain to CSS, so they can't be made synonyms.

Comment: I'd say that `stylesheet` refers to the file itself and techniques on how to include / apply it, while `css` is used for the language and its use for creating designs.

Answer (score 31):

Let's start off by identifying the fact that **[stylesheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stylesheet) has 2,313 questions**. It's not going to be easy, or quick, to burninate it. *Some might even consider it a lost cause.*

As far as the tag wiki, [it was recently revised to include XSLT](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/6727404). This is what it previously said

> A style sheet is made up of style rules that tell a browser how to present a document. Its contains the CSS that is used in HTML file.
>   Questions having the problem related to design will come under this tag.

This is a bit more clear and much less ambiguous, but it's still clear that [stylesheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stylesheet) was the same as [css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css) at one point. The last sentence is still confusing (for a tag excerpt, at least).

> Since we have [css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css) and [xslt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xslt), I see [stylesheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stylesheet) as redundant.

It is redundant and ambiguous, which is a pretty good reason to burninate it. It brings no additional value to questions tagged as [css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css) or [xslt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xslt), which are the exact questions that this tag is for.

- There are [1,663 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stylesheet+css+OR+stylesheet+html+OR+stylesheet+javascript) tagged [stylesheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stylesheet) and [css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css), [html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html), or [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript). These can probably be re-tagged with [css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css) if it isn't already tagged. **But this is a lot of effort for the dominant tag.**
- There are [110 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stylesheet+xml+OR+stylesheet+xslt) tagged [stylesheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stylesheet) and [xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xml) or [xslt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xslt). I suspect that there are actually considerably more, but they aren't tagged correctly. **We should just removed [stylesheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stylesheet) from these.**
- There are [173 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stylesheet+qt+OR+qt-stylesheet+stylesheet+OR+qss+stylesheet) tagged [stylesheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stylesheet) and [qt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/qt), [qss](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/qss), or [qt-stylesheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/qt-stylesheet). I vote that we retag these to use [qt-stylesheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/qt-stylesheet) since it exists. **We should also just removed [stylesheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stylesheet) from these.**

If we just clean up the [xslt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xslt) and [qt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/qt) questions from this tag, **we should be able to merge the rest of the questions in the tag with [css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css)**. This would save a considerable amount of effort in re-tagging the other questions, especially considering there are far less questions that we would need to handle.

Comment: I agree that re-tagging the 110 questions and then merging stylesheet with css would probably be the best option.

Comment: kevin - any suggestions on how we can handle the QT case?

Comment: Beyond XSLT, could SASS, SCSS, and LESS be roped into "stylesheet"? "stylesheet" would then be an all encompassing tag... good or bad, I'm not sure.

Comment: @zamnuts The goal is to merge [stylesheet] with [css] (as it is the dominant tag), so I'm not sure what you mean?

Comment: @KevinBrown these other tags would be a problem if [stylesheet] were to remain, my bad on not being clear.

Comment: @zamnuts When (if) the tag is cleaned up and merged, [non-css questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stylesheet+-css+-html+-javascript+-jquery) are going to have to be evaluated on a case-by-case basis. With any luck, it is at this stage that the low-usage tags will be caught and fixed.

Comment: Does retagging the 110 XSLT questions mean removing the [stylesheet] tag?

Comment: @zamnuts: We generally don't like all-encompassing tags that way.

Comment: @MathiasMüller Yes, I just edited the post to make that more clear.